# Crystal Report formula for most recent date

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two dates fields A.StartDate and B.StartDate and I want the most recent date from both dates fields into a new field. The formula that I used in the formula editor is producing errors

if {B.StartDate} > {A.StartDate} then {B.StartDate} else {A.StartDate}

The error that I am getting says "The result of the selection formula must be a boolean."

Answer (score 0):

You entered that expression in a record selection formula (which requires a True/False as an outcome).

If you intend to use that expression for a new formula, enter it in a new formula -- not in the record selection formula.